# Cakephp: Show image if uploaded or show text if image was not uploaded

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

I am developing a system where the user may upload up to four photos. If the user does not upload a photo I would like that the follow  text will be displayed: 'empty'.

I have prepared the below code however I didn't managed :/ The problem is that when an image is uploaded it still prints 'empty' and the uploaded image does not show up.

```
<?php if (file_exists('../files/collection/photo2/' .$collection['Collection']['photo_dir2'] . '/thumb_' . $collection['Collection']['photo2'])) 
{
  echo $this->Html->image('../files/collection/photo2/' . $collection['Collection']['photo_dir2'] . '/thumb_' . $collection['Collection']['photo2']);}
else
{
  echo ('empty');
}
?>
```

**I appreciate you guidance and help :)**

Comment: Here's a WILD guess:  the file you're checking for using `file_exists()` doesn't exist.

Comment: no I am sure the file is there :)

Comment: If you're 100% positive it's in the correct location (which I would still guess isn't accurate), then check your permissions.

Comment: Dave when I remove the if else statement and I just leave: echo $this->Html->image('../files/collection/photo2/' . $collection['Collection']['photo_dir2'] . '/thumb_' . $collection['Collection']['photo2']); ..... the image is shown...

Comment: I'm sticking with my original wild guess (see answer below for more explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**  The file you're checking for doesn't exist.  Fix your path.

**Detail:**
You're trying to use the same path for both your HTML `<img>` as well as the PHP `file_exists()` check.

The problem is, that the HTML image is looking for a file via the user's browser, where the `file_exists()` method is looking for the file via your server.  The two paths are very rarely the same.

Try using a correct path in your PHP's `file_exists()` method, and it should pass the check.

For example:

```
if(file_exists(APP . 'files' . DS . 'collection' . DS . 'photos2' . $collection['Collection']['photo_dir2'] . DS . 'thumb_' . $collection['Collection']['photo2'])) {
    echo $this->Html->image('../files/collection/photo2/' . $collection['Collection']['photo_dir2'] . '/thumb_' . $collection['Collection']['photo2']);
}
else {
    echo ('empty');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for you patience and guidance :)